# bundlerバージョン確認のエラーについて

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

お世話になっております。
Railsの環境を作成しているものです。
bundlerをインストールし

```
bundler -v
```

でバージョンを確認した際に

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
2: from /home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/bin/bundler:23:in `<main>'
1: from /home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/
   　　　rubybems.rb:308:in 'activate_bin_path'
/home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/
rubygems.rb:289:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem bundler (>= 0.a) 
with executable bundler (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
```

とエラーが発生しバージョンを確認できませんでした。
解決法のご教授よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

同様の症状が本家のStackExchangeでありましたが、その場合は`sudo gem install bundler`で解決したようです。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47026174/find-spec-for-exe-cant-find-gem-bundler-0-a-gemgemnotfoundexception

ただ、本来であれば`rbenv`関係の操作に`sudo`は必要ないため、恐らく`sudo`を使わなくて良い所で`sudo`を使い何かをインストールしてしまっていると思われます。

ですので一旦`~/.rbenv`以下のファイルを全て削除してしまってから再度インストールし直すのが良いのではないでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

今利用しているバージョンの ruby (2.5.0) に対してインストールされている bundler の gem が何かおかしい、もしくは存在していない様子です。

```
gem install bundler
```

を実行すると解決すると思われますが、いかがでしょうか?

Comment: Successfully installed bundler-1.16.1
    1 gem installed
と表示されましたがbundler -vの結果は同じでした。

Comment: @PastelPink なるほど。。だとすると、自分はもう心当たりがないな、と思っています